# Can't delete rows on protected list

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a protected list in sharepoint-excel file, with set unlocked ranges and marked options on editing the list, but I've stumbled upon getting rejected to do actions that I've marked as allowed in options.

My list of options and unlocked ranges:
[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL30G.png) [Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIL0A.png)

My most important question is: where does the "allow users to" apply? To the whole list or just the unlocked ranges?

Becouse, for example, when I try to delete row INSIDE the unlocked range, I cant'!
[Selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dEuS.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOgOy.png)

I never used VBA, but open to it if it can be used in this situation, and if it's possible to create VBA script in online version with sharepoint somehow.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Deleting rows is likely impossible due to the other cells (not in your ranges) being protected, see: https://excel.tips.net/T003004_Inserting_and_Deleting_Rows_in_a_Protected_Worksheet.html . Would it be ok if the user selects the rows he wants to delete and a button calls a macro to unprotect the sheet if the rows are part of the unprotected ranges and deletes them?

Comment: There may be Someone else have created other rules for this table, please check.

Comment: vba will not work in Excel online. Så you can't use macros in the browser or in Teams. You always need to open it in the desktop app. But one can make a setting in sharepoint to open always in desktop app.